# Need explanation over the behavior of C++ code

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, macros

I need a little explanation over how this C++ code is behaving and returning value

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MY_MACRO(n) #n
#define SQR(x) x * x
int main()
{
    //cout<<MY_MACRO(SQR(100))<<endl;
    //cout<< sizeof(SQR(100))<<endl;
    cout<< sizeof(MY_MACRO(SQR(100)))<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As far i am concerned `#n` returns the number of arguments in the `MY_MACRO(n)` But if before that `SQR(100)` will be replaced by `100 * 100` (9 characters if we count spaces) But now `sizeof(9)` should print 4 but Its returning 9 with `cout<< sizeof(MY_MACRO(SQR(100)))<<endl;`

What's the catch behind it?

Comment: Each character is treated as a byte.

Comment: Look at the output of the preprocessor (if you're using g++: g++ -E). Then you'll see cout<< sizeof("SQR(100)")<<endl;

Comment: @Rikayan But here if you see the Macro will replace 100 * 100 to 9 (`MY_MACRO(n) #n`) so it will be sizeof(9)

Comment: @MichaelBrennan It returns 4

Comment: So what you want is to _first_ expand SQR(100) to 100 * 100, then turn _that_ into a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the right definition of `#n`. It is not the number of arguments. It makes it into a string.

Comment: Oh great then it solves my query, and creates 1 more question in my mind..
Do macros work on strings? like `"SQR(100)"` will it be replaced by the string above i.e. `100 * 100`?

Comment: Can you please help with another mystery (Stated in comment above) in my mind?

Comment: No, macros won't touch string literals. If you want to do that, you'll have to modify the "string" first, then make it a literal later on.

Comment: Ohkay Great! and that solves the questions popping in my mind :)

Answer (score 5):

After macro substitution your code will be converted to

`sizeof("SQR(100)");`

which will give 9 as size of string literal including the terminating `'\0'`.

`#n` will make the argument as string, its not the number of argument

For example :

```
#define display( n ) printf( "Result" #n " = %d", Result##n )
int Result99 = 78;

display( 99 ) ; // Will output -> Result99 = 78
```

Comment: But will SQR(100) won't be replaced with `100 * 100`?